# Margins too Small work around - Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, margins

How do I defeat the "Settings you Choose for the left and right margins, columns spacing, or paragraph indents are too large for the page width in some sections."

I need margins <.5" and it will not give it too me.   This is not being set by the printer driver as I have tested the driver and it can print very close to the edge.

Thanks,

Comment: As it turns out I can drag my margins smaller on the ruler, but I can't set them from the page layout menu.  However, the size in the page layout menu does reflect the size of the margins I dragged.

Comment: What happens if you try 0.5 cm?

Comment: Same error, when putting .5 in one of the margins on the page layout menu.

Comment: Did you try [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)?